# i want to record response get from statuscallback twilio

Tags: php, twilio

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);

require 'Services/Twilio.php';

$version = "2010-04-01";

$sid = 'xxxxxx';
$token = 'xxxxxx';

$phonenumber = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, $version);

try {

    $call = $client->account->calls->create($phonenumber, "3104200693", "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml", array(
        "Method" => "GET",
        "StatusCallback" => "http://localhost/twilio/call-response.php",
        "StatusCallbackMethod" => "GET",
        "StatusCallbackEvent" => array("initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed"),
        "IfMachine" => "Continue",
    ));

    //header("Location: http://localhost/twilio/call-response.php");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

This is my twilio code to call a number, i am successfully calling with this, but i want to store response in database like call completed or not and if answered then who answered call human or machine.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The Twilio servers will send an HTTP request to the URL given as `StatusCallback`. Quite obviously, hopefully, Twilio cannot contact your `localhost`. 1) your computer is probably not physically reachable from outside your network, and 2) `localhost` is something different for everyone.

You need to provide a URL which is publicly accessible from the internet. That means you either need to run your code in a server, or you use a service like http://ngrok.com to establish a tunnel to your local machine during development.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think `"StatusCallback" => "http://localhost/twilio/call-response.php"` will make you get call response. You should give a server url.

For example

```
"StatusCallback" => "http://example.com/twilio/call-response.php"
```

In **call-response.php**,

```
<?php

file_put_contents(__DIR__."/status_log.txt", json_encode($_REQUEST));
// twilio call status and other sata will be written to this file. Please check this file after call.
// I am giving because i dont know correct twilio returning params

?>
```

[More info here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls)